# How do I set -DmyConfig=whatever when running a java program through "run file" in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm using netbeans 6.7.1 and I have a maven web project (war file).

I'd like to profile part of the project by running a java class with a main method.
I need to specify a -DconfigDir=whatever when running this program.

How do you specify this in netbeans?

In eclipse I simply edit the run configurations.
I've only seen where you can setup run configurations for "jar" projects, not "war" projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can do this in NetBeans 6.9.
[image]